# Adding extra value/parameter to KeyValue pair

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have the following `List<KeyValue<string, int>>` below that I use in `View` of one of my application. It works, but I'm trying to extend it, *if possible*, by adding an extra *parameter/value* to the `KeyValue` pair.

Each one of the pair has a specific color, I'll like to pass to inline css color property. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
     var result = MyClass.GetOrder(item);
     <h2>@item.Date.Substring(0,4)</h2>
     <p style="color:@result[0].Value3">@result[0].Key , @result[0].Value</p>
     <p style="color:@result[0].Value3">@result[1].Key , @result[1].Value</p>
     <p style="color:@result[0].Value3">@result[2].Key , @result[2].Value</p>
     <p style="color:@result[0].Value3">@result[3].Key , @result[3].Value</p>                   
 }
```

Static Method

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetOrder(MyClass myclass)
{
    var NameVal = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>(myclass.Name1, Convert.ToInt32(myclass.Val1)),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>(myclass.Name2, Convert.ToInt32(myclass.Val2)),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>(myclass.Name3, Convert.ToInt32(myclass.Val3)),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>(myclass.Name4, Convert.ToInt32(myclass.Val4))
    };
    var result = NameVal.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value);
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a list of KeyValuePairs over a Dictionary?

Comment: no reason........

Comment: You cannot add a 3rd value to a `KeyValuePair`. You will find this far easier is you just use a view model containing the 3 properties your want and pass a collection of that model to the view

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the values you want inside a data structure, then use that as the type for the "Value" part of the KeyValuePair.

```
public class Data
{
    public int IntValue;
    public string StringValue;
    public bool BoolValue;
}
```

And implement it like this:

```
var list = new List<KeyValue<string, Data>>();
```

Although frankly, unless you have a specific reason to need to access the pairs by `int` index, I'd highly recommend just using a Dictionary.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Data>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a struct/class, and then past a IEnumerable of that class/struct into your view. Also, just for future reference, a `List<KeyValuePair>` is the same thing as a [dictionary](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary).

**Update:** Functionally, the two are actually NOT the same, however a dictionary is far better suited for what the OP's trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not quite. A `List` stores its data sequentially and retrieves its values by `int` index, whereas a `Dictionary` stores its data in a hash table retrieves its values by a key of designated type.

Comment: @Abion47 Yep, you are 100% correct! Poor choice of words on my part.